# How to lock Iphone device with my app?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I am working on an app with passcode locking option(pic1). When I enter correct password it enters into the app.When I enter wrong password it will perform some other action(pic2).
[image]
After some time the app goes into the sleep state,when the app comes to active state we have to enter the password again.

Here my requirement is I want to open the "passcode locking screen" (pic1.,which was created by me) after unlocking the device,(pic3.,which is default locking option in Iphone). Unless I enter the correct passcode the "passcode screen" should stick to the window. It should not move to any other screen (pic4., screen with group of app icons) though I click the button of theiphone.

This requirement is killing my time, I don't mind to post sample code or tutorials if you have gone through.

Comment: Try to reformat you question it's really hard read, also you are missing the picture and the code you have tried to solve this problem your self.

Comment: I think you forgot to link to some pictures.

Comment: I think you forgot that Xcode is unrelated to this. This is not a question about the IDE but about using the iOS/Cocoa Touch APIs.

Comment: One of the things you're asking for is whether you can prevent the iPhone from going to the home screen when the home button is pressed. You can't.

Comment: not only home screen.it should not go to any other screen(even the screen consists of icons shown in pic 4) @mrurg

Comment: u mentioned "It should not move to any other screen (pic4., screen with group of app icons) though I click the button of theiphone." what's tis! u can't

Comment: thats the requirement what my client asked dude @NAZIK

Comment: u should work at apple to do that

Comment: if this wont work.. How many apps like https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/best-phone-security-pro/id465627351?mt=8  are created ? Please help i am working on the same concept

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can't do this using a non-jailbreak iPhone. an app cannot prohibit the user from switching to another app (and it cannot modify another app)

that applies to the springboard (pic4) too of course

Comment: can we do this on jailbreak iphone ? clarify my doubt @Daij-Djan

Comment: I am not sure about that as I rarely deal with jailbreaks... I strongly think so but honestly I don't know 100%

Comment: if this wont work.. How many apps like https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/best-phone-security-pro/id465627351?mt=8  are created ? Please help i am working on the same concept

Comment: I even bought the app so I could validate my point. ;) :: it doesn't work as it doesn't lock anything. what it does is play a sound when you leave the app without code || but ono until you kill it ;)